# Are these tables generated by aspnet_reqsql.exe necessary for an ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Problem**

I'm using aspnet_regsql.exe for the first time to populate the database for use with our ASP.NET MVC app.

Upon using it I see that there are two types of table naming conventions, with the table names both seeming to describe the same data. However only one of these types actually seems to be used by the WAF.

**Example**

For example, both `AspNetUsers` and `aspnet_Users` exist, as well as `AspNetRoles` and `aspnet_Roles`. In both examples, it is the former table's naming convention in use.

**Expanded Question**

Are both sets of tables necessary for use in an ASP.NET MVC app? Only one set seems to be in use.

If both sets aren't necessary, how best I avoid it? I know aspnet_regsql.exe has an `-sqlexportonly` option, so I could manually edit out table creations there, but it seems a bit hacky.

And again, if both sets aren't necessary, can this duplication be avoided elsewhere (if it happens with stored procedures too, for example)?

Comment: Actually, none of them are mandatory. `aspnet_regsql.exe` installs the old Membership Provider For ASP.NET (of .net framework. v2). When you create a new asp.net mvc app, using Visual Studio 2013/2015 template, it  will use ASP.NET Identity, which is the new provider for membership. In short, `aspnet_Users` is the old one, `AspNetUsers` is the new one. You should choose only one!

Comment: Hi there, and thanks for your reply. What about situations in which, with a pre-existing app, you create a new database (say for separate testing purposes) and point the app to this new database?

Comment: in a pre-existing app, I would not change anything, and use the old provider if necessary. In fact, it is just a matter of style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, aspnet_regsql is no longer required in ASP.NET MVC. Once you create a new ASP.NET MVC project (with of course "forms authentication"), and run the website, these tables get created as soon as you successfully register your first user. aspnet_Users, aspnet_Roles, etc are not needed.

You can safely delete them, if you can't start from scratch.

Comment: Is there any way to create these tables outside of the IDE?

Say for example you were giving this app to a client who would had their own database server on site. When setting up the database for them, would we still have to use VS to create the tables?

Still somewhat new to ASP.NET, so apologies if this is a silly question.

Comment: No, you don't need VS to create those tables. When you successfully register a first user through the ASP.NET MVC application after deploying to client-end, the application will take care to create these tables in the database, as they wont be pre-existing. To summarize, in case of pre-existing database, but in absence of pre-existing membership tables (i.e., AspNetUsers, etc), the MVC application will create these tables on its own, and it doesn't require VS.

Comment: And the same is true of any stored procedures that are initially not in the DB?

Comment: Just checked, while what you said is true of tables, I'm missing all of the ASP.NET stored procedures. So when I try to log in with the created user, I get an error saying that {aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion} is missing. Is aspnet_regsql.exe the only option for this?

Comment: ASP.NET Identity doesn't require and not uses the stored procedures we used to had with asp.net membership earlier.. That's why if you create a new MVC project with a new database, you won't see those stored procedures. However, in your case, as you are using existing database, this might be related to some configuration. Are you using custom role provider? does your web.config contains <RoleManager> configurations?

Comment: You're totally right, I changed the RoleManager details and it fixed the issue. The problem is that I am jumping into this stuff without having fully studied ASP.NET MVC. Anyhow, thanks for your answer and I'll accept your solution :) As an aside, would you recommend any books or material for learning ASP.NET MVC?